# Image Slider with border colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

[image: I want to achieve this]

Recently I'm using an image slider to my angular project then I need to add the background colour to each images' border like my attachment. I used custom CSS class to fulfil this but I cannot find way to apply this class correctly. But when I using DOM I can do that, My CSS class is as follows

```
border-boundry{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

NPM Package Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-image-slider
Demo: https://sanjayv.github.io/ng-image-slider/

Answer (score 0):

What if you use one of the classes you have on the right like ng-image-slider-container ?
Try to add "background-color: red;" on the class ".ng-image-slider", is this what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the library you're using is enforcing css rules with `!important` flag. So you can either try to override it with `!important` yourself (not recommended ), or try to use already existing classes by adding more css to them...

Comment: but I want to add a border to the single image not only whole slider's images

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in the `styles.css` of your angular app. With this you get the selected image surrounded with a frame.

```css
.selected-image {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```